# netstandard 2.0 nuget reference results in error CS0012 on TFS build

Tags: c#, tfs, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I've created project_A targeting .NET Standard 2.0 and made a nuget package from it. Its dependencies look as follow:

[project_A dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CR25z.png)

Then this nuget is being used in project_B which results in errors during build (but only on TFS), which are:

> error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

[project_B dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0s37.png)

It looks like after deletion of project_A nuget reference in project_B the errors are gone. Adding System.Runtime as nuget to the project_B doesn't fix it.

Thanks in advice for any ideas.

Comment: Is the dotnet SDK installed on the build server?

Comment: @DavidG yes, it is.

Comment: Did you restore packages before building?

Comment: @DanielMann yes, there is a restore step which passing successfully.